# How to invoke command programmatically passing to it a parameter?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I was trying the bellow snippet, but the invoked command is executed with empty parameter map.

```java
ICommandService service = (ICommandService) ((IServiceLocator) PlatformUI.getWorkbench())
                         .getService(ICommandService.class);

Command command = service.getCommand(Constants.COMMAND_ID);

ExecutionEvent eventWithParam = new ExecutionEvent(command, 
         Collections.singletonMap(Constants.COMMAND_PARAM, "true"), null, null);

command.execute(eventWithParam);
```

The issue seems to be that when it goes to compatibility layer is looses `PARM_MAP` in `HandlerServiceHanlder.execute` method.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: `Command.execute` (which is deprecated) does not touch the `ExecutionEvent` - it just passes it straight to the current handler. Show us your handler code.

Comment: Invoked handler:
public class RunHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {
 @Override
 public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
  String sIsCleanup = event.getParameter(Constants.COMMAND_PARAM);
  if (sIsCleanup != null) {
   isCleanup = Boolean.parseBoolean(sIsCleanup);
  }

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @greg-449, you inspired me to keep digging ;).

In the end it turned out that neither the `Command.excecute` nor `Command.executeWithChecks` does work (all parameters are lost whilst passing to `HandlerServiceHandler`).

But that reminds me that there was something like `HandlerService` - which basically can do the job. Here is the snippet:

```java
IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) ((IServiceLocator) PlatformUI.getWorkbench())
                    .getService(IHandlerService.class);

Parameterization[] params = new Parameterization[] { new Parameterization(
                    command.getParameter(Constants.COMMAND_PARAM), "true") };
ParameterizedCommand parametrizedCommand = new ParameterizedCommand(command, params);
handlerService.executeCommand(parametrizedCommand, null);
```